# How to poup the dynamically generated bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a wordpress site. I am displaying the Events of the website on a page and I have added load more button on clicking more available events are displyed on the page via ajax. On clicking the events the Bootstrap modal appears displaying the details of the event. Those Events which are loaded while the page loads their Modal is loading fine. when I get the events via ajax their modal is not opening. I dont know why i have tried to get the modal via jquery On function but that didnt worked.
Here is my code.

Javascript code to call the events via ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var ajaxURL = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

        var perpage = parseInt('<?php echo $perpage; ?>');

        var offset  = 0;



    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {



    $(".load_more").click(function(){

        offset += perpage;

        // This does the ajax request

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            url: ajaxURL,

            data: {

                'action':'example_ajax_request',

                'offset' : offset,

                'perpage' : perpage

            },

            success:function(data) {

                $(".event-row").append(data);

                $('.dynamic').click(function() {
                    $("#dynamic_modal").modal({
                        show: true
                    });
                });


                if(data != '')

                {

                   $("#offset").val(offset);     

                }
            }
        }); 
    });
});

</script>
```

Here is my Code where i created the dynamic HTML for Events

```
function example_ajax_request() {

    $returnStr = '';
    $perpage = $_POST['perpage'];
    $offset  = $_POST['offset'];
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => $perpage, 'offset' =>$offset, 'orderby' => 'asc' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $i=0;
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            $returnStr .= '<div class="menu-category list-group ">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="img-1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dynamic" id="'.$loop->post->ID.'" data-modal="modal" data-target=".'.$loop->post->ID.'"><img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->post->ID, 'thumbnail') ).'" class="img-responsive"></a></div>';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="img-1-text">';
            $returnStr .= '<h1 class="event-heading-one">'.esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID).'</h1>';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="date-time-event">';
            $link = get_post_meta($loop->post->ID, 'eventdate', $single);
            $timestamp = strtotime($link[$i]);
            $date[$i] = date('M d, Y', $timestamp);
            $returnStr .= '<div class="date">date :<span class="event-span">'.$date[$i].'</span></div>';
            $time = get_post_meta($loop->post->ID, 'event_time', $single);
            $returnStr .= '<div class="time">time :<span class="event-span">'.$time[$i].'</span></div>';
            $location = get_post_meta($loop->post->ID, 'event_location', $single);
            $number = get_post_meta($loop->post->ID, 'event_number', $single);
            $website = get_post_meta($loop->post->ID, 'event_website', $single);
            $returnStr .= '<div class="event-text">'. $location[$i].', '.$number[$i].'  '.$website[$i].'</div>';
            $returnStr .= '</div>';
            $returnStr .= '</div></div>';

            $returnStr .= '<div class="dynamic_modal modal fade '.$loop->post->ID.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="modal-content">';
            $returnStr .= '<section id="pop-up-modal-windows">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="container">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="row">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="row">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="pop-up-modal">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="left-modal-pop-up">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="modal-image">';
            $returnStr .= '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->post->ID, 'full') ) .'" class="img-responsive">';
            $returnStr .= '</div>';
            $returnStr .= '</div>';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="row">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="abc">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="modal-pop-up-heading">';

            $link = get_post_meta($loop->post->ID, 'eventdate', $single);
            $timestamp = strtotime($link[$i]);
            $day[$i] = date('d', $timestamp);
            $month[$i] = date('M', $timestamp); 

            $returnStr .= '<div class="date-of-event-modal">'.$day[$i].'<br>'.$month[$i].'</div>';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="name-of-event-inner">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="event-text">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="modal-new-heading">'.esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID).'';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="event-of-date-text">';
            $location= get_post_meta($loop->post->ID, 'event_location', $single);
            $time = get_post_meta($loop->post->ID, 'event_time', $single);
            $returnStr .= ''.$location[$i].'<br>Shows start at '.$time[$i].'';
            $returnStr .= '</div></div></div></div></div>';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="modal-pop-up-text">'.esc_attr($loop->post->post_content ? $loop->post->post_content : $loop->post->ID).'</div>';
            $returnStr .= '</div></div></div></div>';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="row"></div></div>';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="modal-pop-right">';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="modal-pop-right-heading">event location</div>';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="border-bottom"></div>';
            $returnStr .= '<div class="map-event-location">';
            //$link = get_post_meta($loop->post->ID, 'event_map', $single);
            //$returnStr .= '<iframe width="253" height="176" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.it/maps?q='. $link[$i]['address'].'&output=embed"></iframe>';
            $returnStr .= '</div></div>';
            $returnStr .= '</div></div>';
            $returnStr .= '</div></div>';
            //$returnStr .= '</div></div>';
            $returnStr .= '</section>';


         $i++;                                      
    endwhile;
    echo $returnStr;
   die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

Any Help??

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `die()` from the end of `example_ajax_request()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reviews i have got the solution just call the modal popup inside the ajax function and it works :)